Audio is sampled at 48 kHz, or 48000 samples per second. Does that mean 48000 bits (or 6000 bytes) of storage?
How does the sampling rate of an audio signal translate into memory capacity?
Does one sample translates into one bit in the memory, and hence 48000 bits of storage needed for a single second of audio?
How is this calculated?

For raw, uncompressed audio, the number of bits per second is the product of three values:
$$
numBitsPerSecond = f_{sampleRate}*numBitsPerSample*numStreams
$$
where $f_{sampleRate}=48000$ in your example. Typical values for audio bitwidths are 8 or 16 bits per sample, though for 48 kHz sample rate, I would expect 16 or more bits per sample, and you might have as many as 24 bits per sample for very high-quality representation (even if the effective number of bits - ENOB - is less than this 24 bit representation). Lower quality audio like telephony may use 8 bits per sample at 8 kHz; CD audio uses 44.1 kHz sample rate with 16 bits per sample per stream.
The number of streams also plays a role. Stereo audio with 2 streams (L/R) will double the storage, for example.
For example, a stereo audio stream with 16 bit samples at 48 kHz sample rate would be
$$
numBitsPerSecond = 48e3 * 16 * 2 = 1.536 Mbps
$$
Typically, audio files are compressed, taking advantage of predictability in the audio stream. Well-known compressors for high-fidelity audio are MP3, WMA, AAC, etc. These lead to lower bitrates required for the compressed audio stream versus storing the raw, sampled datastream, and one can choose to compromise audio quality in exchange for lower bitrate.

I up arrowed this, but I wish you would select a better set of symbols in your equations and description.


Audio is sampled at 48 kHz, or 48000 samples per second.

No.  Audio is often sampled at 48000 samples per second.  It can be sampled at a number of different rates.  The old-time digital telephony standard was 8000 samples per second.  CDs sample at 44100 samples per second.  Some high-end audio equipment samples at 96000 samples per second or even 192000 samples per second.
By definition, 44100 samples per second is the minimum high-fidelity sampling rate.  6000 is probably the minimum for good intelligibility -- the Bell System chose 8000 back in the 1930's or 1940's because it was fast enough to not noticeably degrade the phone quality at the time -- that was the rate in use back in the 1990's, and may still be in use today.

Does one sample translates into one bit in the memory

No.  Theoretically the number of bits per sample is anything at all; in practice, raw sound data* ranges from 12 bits/sample (good enough for understanding what's said over a telephone) to 32 bits (way more than enough, but higher bit counts excites the audiophiles who spend good money on cables dipped in liquid nitrogen).

How is this calculated?

Multiply the sampling rate by the bits per sample, then account for any compression.

* Note that telephone audio is transmitted at 8 bits/sample -- but it's not raw.  It's undergone nonlinear prescaling, called "companding", that gives the quiet bits around 12 bits of effective resolution, but less resolution for the loud bits.
